# git-shell merging to a different path

Tags: git, merge, git-bash

I have one problem with my git remote repository. I have create a git user for a git-shell access.

When someone join in the shell the home path is **/home/git/**, and this is ok. The problem is: my repository path is **/var/www/** and I want give the possibility at git user to merge inside this directory but without using the bash shell (so I don't give the possibility to use *cd* for navigate inside the server).

Git-shell have the capabilities to execute **merge** command? And this last have the possibility to specify the also the path?

I don't find anything esplain the merge for git-shell.

I was thinking to create a .sh script executable by web.
But give the function directly by the git shell could be solve some security issues already from the base.

Thanks in advance,
Mauro.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you want to expose the repo on a web server, there are better ways to do this; e.g. set up an apache web server and configure it with git, something like what's explained here: http://kasunh.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/git-over-https/

Comment: This could be a good idea, thanks.
But in any case I feel more safe behind the public key, this why I try to get a solution in a shell side.

Comment: If you only want to access the repo through ssh, why are you trying to "merge" it into a repo in /var/www ?

Comment: Thanks Steinar for your faster replies.
Basic I have the main repor in a directory /var/www/projectname, inside I have some branches so:
/var/www/projectname/:
 - [branches]:
  -- master *
  -- user_a
  -- user_b

So user_a push to his branch and user_b do the same to his branch but they need to merge to a master one.

At the moment they can push to the remote repository ( /var/www/projectname ) but they need to merge with the master.

For this I activate the git-shell (also for push and fetch). Do you understand my git structure? Is something I can do better?

Comment: I finally solved with simple bash script.
I execute this behind php, and it work. Thanks for all.

Comment: Could you post the solution as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to do a Work-around for this and temporary is working for me.
But I don't suggest you to expose the script in the same way I do, and try to figurate other alternatives.

Basic inside my git repository I create this bash script.

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT
git merge [name_of_branch_one]
git merge [name_of_branch_two]
```

After that I create a simple php function where for call the sh script, and looks like:

```
$exec = exec("sh /Your_Git_Repository_dir/merge.sh");
if($exec){
    print_r($exec);
}
```

I hope this help.